# Feeding inputs to tf.contrib.learn estimators directly

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am having trouble using the DNNRegressor estimator from TensorFlow's tf.contrib.learn. In the [documentation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNRegressor) of the estimator two methods for providing inputs are presented.

The first method uses the *input_fn* function, which, as described, should be used for pre-processing and feeding the input to the estimators, and the second method feeds the input directly. Examples:

```
def input_function:
    ...
    return feature_cols, label

estimator.fit(input_fn=input_function, steps=...)
```

In this case *feature_cols* is a *dict* with:

- Key: *string* specifying the column name,
- Value: *tf.constant* specifying the column values,

*label* is a single *tf.constant* column containing the labels.

This worked.

```
X_train = ...
y_train = ...
estimator.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, steps=...)
```

In this case I don't know what to feed in as *X* and *y*. I have tried the following:

- Ordinary numpy arrays. This was a long shot and did not work with. The error message is: `KeyError: 'my_column0'`
- Pandas DataFrame with columns corresponding to the defined column names (defined on initialization of the estimator). I would again get the same KeyError, even though the key should be there now.
- Pass X=*feature_cols* and y=*label* defined in the same way as in the case of the input_fn above. This yields: `ValueError: Inputs cannot be tensors. Please provide input_fn.`

I also tried other combinations with *dict* and numpy arrays, but nothing worked. I would like to be able to make this work using the second method, since this is also useful for passing the objects to the *evaluate* and *predict*. Does anyone know the correct format for this?
Also, is there a way to simply pass numpy arrays?

Thank you!

tl;dr
What should the inputs to tf.contrib.learn estimator be in order to feed them directly using `estimator.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, steps=...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I missed the following warning:
SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED. They will be removed after 2016-12-01. Instructions for updating: Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn. Example conversion: est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))

It is strange that the arguments are still there after 2016-12-01 though.